# keypress event is detecting multiple keypresses when a key is pressed only once in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, keypress, event-listener

I added an event listener to the HTML document, and did console.log(event).
But when I pressed down a key, console shows multiple events of same keypress.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    console.log(event);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

use **keyup** instead of keydown:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    console.log(e);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is worng because you used `e` as parameter. But you `console.log(event)` Use `console.log(e)`

Comment: Although a bit weird, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event. So it will do the same.

Comment: yeah but its "Deprecated"

Answer (score 0):

your function is taking e as a parameter while your console.log is showing event instead of parameter.
use this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    console.log(e);
})
```

Instead of this :

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    console.log(event);
})
```

you can also use onkeydown event handler :

```
document.addEventListener("onkeydown", function(e){
    console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: You might want to re-read the OPs problem,  although using the global event is discouraged and the OP should change it, it still works.  Also try and avoid upvote scrounging, it's a bit creepy.. :)